How to apply `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in cgo
I use following main.go call cpp lib so
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/draft/go_call_cpp -lprogress
#include "progress_lib.h"

// Callback function to be called from C++
extern void progressCallback(int progress);
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

//export progressCallback
func progressCallback(progress C.int) {
    fmt.Printf("Progress: %d%%\n", progress)
    if progress == 100 {
        wg.Done()
    }
}

func main() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        C.do_work(C.progress_callback(C.progressCallback))
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}

when I first export LD_LIBRARY_PATH and then run code, the code work well
~/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/draft/go_call_cpp $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/draft/go_call_cpp:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
~/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/draft/go_call_cpp $ go run main.go
Progress: 0%
Progress: 10%

when I run code directly, it raise err:
~/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/draft/go_call_cpp $ go run main.go 
/tmp/go-build2581226776/b001/exe/main: error while loading shared libraries: libprogress.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
exit status 127

I hope don't export LD_LIBRARY_PATH in cli, but put export LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my main.go, how should I do?

Does this answer your question? How to use a dynamically linked library from relative path

I use -Wl, -rpath instead export LD_LIBRARY_PATH, following is full code
package main

/*

#cgo CFLAGS: -I${SRCDIR}

#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR} -lprogress -Wl,-rpath,${SRCDIR}

#include "progress_lib.h"

// Callback function to be called from C++

extern void progressCallback(int progress);

*/

import "C"

import (

"fmt"

"sync"

)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

//export progressCallback

func progressCallback(progress C.int) {

fmt.Printf("Progress: %d%%\n", progress)

if progress == 100 {

wg.Done()

}

}

func main() {

wg.Add(1)

go func() {

C.do_work(C.progress_callback(C.progressCallback))

}()

wg.Wait()

}

